# Bad request error when calling a custom action from JS in CRM V9

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I created a custom action in my CRM online V9 with 2 parameters an entity reference to contact and a string.

I checked that the schema name is correct (upper and lower case) and even tried to use rest builder to generate the code but I keep getting a "Bad Request" error.

Here is my code:

```
var parameters = {};
var contact = {};
contact.primarykeyid = "49A0E5B9-88DF-E311-B8E5-6C3BE5A8B200";//I added an hard coded value for testing
contact["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact";
parameters.Contact = contact;
parameters.Text = "Some Text";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/new_CreateSMSrecord", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
```

Comment: can you figure out if the issue is with action itself or params? try to remove params one by one.. also change the 'false' flag in req.open to 'true' & see if works in async mode..

Comment: Hey Arun,
The issue is with the contact parameter, but I don't know what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to find the problem
I changed the code of the contact parameter and that solved the issue,
here is my updated code:

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.Contact = { "contactid": "49A0E5B9-88DF-E311-B8E5-6C3BE5A8B200", "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact" }
parameters.Text = "I'm from JS";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/new_CreateSMSrecord",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var results = data;
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```